# A Logarithmic Definite Integral Problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, polylogarithm

I was trying to solve the integral
$$
A=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x + 1}\, dx.
$$

Firstly, I was trying to solve the indefinite one
$$
I(x)=\int\frac{x}{e^x + 1}\, dx.
$$
By subtitution $t = e^x$, fraction decomposition, and lastly partial integration for the second integrand i get :

$\displaystyle I(x)=\frac{x^2}{2} - x\cdot\ln(e^x + 1) - \text{Li}_2(-e^x)$ (ignoring the constant)

Where $\text{Li}_2(-e^x) = \sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \dfrac{(-e^x)^k}{k}$

so then of course :

$A = I(x\to \infty) - I(0)$

The result that i get on calculator is $A = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$,

which makes sense considering $\dfrac{x}{e^x+1} \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ (thus it has finite area).

But when i tried to do it manually by hand (with fourier series to compute $I(0)$ and Convergence test for $I(x\to \infty)$)

i get : $A = \text{divergent} - \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$

edit : for $I(x\to\infty)$ i do L'hopital and Convergence test

$I(x\to \infty) = N-K$ where $\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-2\ln(e^x+1))}{2}$ and $\displaystyle K=\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k\geq1} (-1)^k \cdot \dfrac{e^{kx}}{k}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-2\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x-\ln(e^x+1)}{\cfrac{2}{x}}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{1-\dfrac{2e^x}{e^x+1}}{-\cfrac{2}{x^2}}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{e^x(e^x+1)-e^{2x}}{(e^x+1)^2}}{\cfrac{1}{x^3}}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}}{\cfrac{1}{x^3}}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x^3e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{(3x^2+x^3)e^x}{2(e^x+1)\cdot e^x}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \dfrac{1}{4}\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{3x^2+x^3}{e^x+1}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \dfrac{1}{4}\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{6x+3x^2}{e^x}$

$\displaystyle N=\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(x-\ln(e^x+1))}{2} = \dfrac{3}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x+1}{e^x} \to 0$

and for K :

$\displaystyle K=\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k\geq1} (-1)^k \cdot \dfrac{e^{kx}}{k}$

$\displaystyle K= \sum\limits_{k\geq1} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k} \cdot \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{kx} $

$ K= \sum\limits_{k\geq1} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k} \cdot\infty = \infty$

other things i tried : using series representation of $\dfrac{1}{x+1}$, change $x$ into $e^x$, multiply the series by $x$ and then integrate it, i still get Divergent-$\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$

Anyone can point out where it went wrong done manually ?

Edit : **Resolved**

So all i need to do is just turn $\dfrac{x}{e^x+1}$ into $\dfrac{xe^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1}$ then use maclaurin series for $\dfrac{1}{x+1}$

Comment: Why do you think $I(x\to\infty)$ is divergent? You should show your work for that step.

Comment: As $x\to\infty$, the expression for $I(x)$ involves several terms that diverges. So it is a typical $\infty-\infty$ type indeterminate, and you have to study the asymptotic behavior of the expression $I(x)$ to find the limit.

Comment: well because i was doing convergence test for the series, also doing L'hopital few times (until i get $-\dfrac{3x^2+x^2}{4\cdot(e^x+1)}$) on the function at the left side, which led to conclusion $I(x\to\infty)$ is divergent

Comment: According to convergence test the series diverges to infinity

Comment: @SangchulLee does that mean i have to approximate ? if so what approximation is it ?

Comment: Try $t=e^{-x}$ instead of $t=e^x$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282982/improper-integral-of-fracxex1). The trick is to multiply top and bottom by $e^{-x}$ before expanding (then your second idea of using the series for $(1+x)^{-1}$ will work).

Comment: @NoName thanks, that was what i needed.

Comment: @NoName No, I forgot about the sign flipping. I'll just remove it, I think JamboRambo has the point.